# What is the definition of "recently added" in my iTunes playlists?

Tags: itunes, playlist

What is the definition of "recently added" in my iTunes playlists?  Are these songs that I have purposely added or could they be those songs added by iTunes because of my Genius playlist. I need to know if these songs could have been added by someone other than me.

Answer (score 1):

The "Recently Added" playlist is a smart playlist that is automatically generated based on the rules that define it. I have removed it from my machine, but if you right click it and select `Edit Smart Playlist`, you can see its rules. The playlist contains songs you've added yourself "recently" (you'll have to check yourself to see what "recently" means)

Answer (score 0):

They're songs added to your iTunes library *by you*.

It's a smart playlist with what I believe by default shows music added in the last two weeks.